# Shell Script to redirect to different directory and create a list file

Tags: shell

```
             src_dir="/export/home/destination"
             list_file="client_list_file.txt"
             file=".csv"

             echo "src directory="$src_dir
             echo "list_file="$list_file
             echo "file="$file

             cd /export/home/destination

             touch $list_file

             x=`ls *$file | sort >$list_file`



            if [ -s $list_file ]
             then
            echo "List File is available, archiving now"
                    y=`tar -cvf mystuff.tar $list_file`
             else
            echo "List File is not available"
             fi
```

The above script is working fine and it's supposed to create a list file of all .csv files and tar's it.

However I am trying to do it from a different directory while running the script, so it should go to the destination directory and makes a list file with all the .csv in destination directory and make a .tar from the list file(i.e archive the list file)

So i am not sure what to change

Comment: what result do you have? i think this script will list all the csv files in `/export/home/destination` and make a tarball in that directory. isn't that what you want? btw, you don't recieve stdout if you won't use it.

Comment: my current result is that it takes all the csv in the script location directory(where i actually script.sh is located), so that is not whats wanted.  I want it to change directory to a destination directory and than take .csv in that directory and put it in list file and archive it

Comment: The only way I can see that this is not pulling files from `/export/home/destination` is if  the `cd /export/home/destination` fails, either because it doesn't exist, or you don't have sufficient permissions. I think I would go with `(cd /export/home/destination; find . -depth 1 -type f -name "*.csv" -print | tar -cvfT mystuff.tar -)`, though, and dispense with parsing the output of `ls` and all the unnecessary variable assignments and temporary files...

Comment: simply `tar -cvf $src_dir/mystuff.tar $src_dir/*.csv`. btw, you should name your destination path as `src_dir`. this name is confusing.

Comment: ahh... you shouldn't name your blah blah. forgive my typing.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr it has to tar the list file not the csv's. how can i direct the the list file to src_dir?
1. get all the csv to list_file
2. compress the list_file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a lot of tricks in filename handling. the one thing you should know is file naming under POSIX sucks. commands like `ls` or `find` may not return the expected result(but 99% of the time they will). so here is what you have to do to get the list of files truely:

```
for file in $src_dir/*.csv; do
    echo `basename $file` >> $src_dir/$list_file
done
tar cvf $src_dir/mystuff.tar $src_dir/$list_file
```

maybe you should learn bash in a serious manner and try to google first before you asking question in SO next time.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html